# react-select: disable default styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

How to disable default react-select styles ?
react-select is not in the center of container, that's why i must use `margin-bottom`, but it's not good solution.
without margin-bottom:
[without margin-bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y15m3.png)
css

```
.header {
  height: 98px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #222968;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.header__title {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
}

.header__select{
  height: 64px;
  width: 169px;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
}
```

Script:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [ 
  { value: 'userName', label: 'username' },
  { value: 'logout', label: 'logout' },
]

export class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='header'>
        <span className='header__title'>Task Assistant Service</span>
        <Select
          className='header__select'
          options= {options}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.header__select{
  height: 64px;
```

Here your `height` setting is causing the problem.

If you remove the height it'll be perfectly centered. So, you don't have to change the margin.

[image].

And if you want to set custom height. Then you have to use a custom style like:

```
const customStyles = {
  control: base => ({
    ...base,
    height: 64,
    minHeight: 64
  })
};
```

And apply in `Select` component like:

```
styles={customStyles}
```

Applying `height: 64px` will look like this:

[image]

**Check detailed demo at** [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-volhard-o1kln?file=/src/App.js)